# Expectation value of a max funtion

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let $b_t$, with  $t = 1,...,T$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables taking on the values $b_t = \pm1$. I would like to verify the following claim from a textbook: [image]

In actuality $T$ is a random variable as well but for simplicity assume that $E_0[T] = T$ is fixed.

I have worked out an example for $T = 2$, and I am finding an answer which is inconsistent with the stated result:

$$E(\theta_T) = \sum_{b_1, b_2}p(b_1)p(b_2)\theta_T(b_1, b_2) = P(b_1 = 1)P(b_2 = 1)2 + P(b_1 = -1)P(b_2 = 1)1 + P(b_1 = 1)P(b_2 = -1)1 +P(b_1 = -1)P(b_2 = -1)2\,.$$

Using the fact that the variables are identically distributed, one has

$$E(\theta_T) = 2\Big(P(b_t = 1)^2 + P(b_t = 1)P(b_t = -1) + P(b_t = -1)^2\Big),$$

which does not match the stated result for $T = 2$. Can someone point out an error in my calculation?

Comment: Does $t$ start at $0$ (as suggested in your first line)? It seems that in your calculation you start at $t=1$.

Comment: It starts at $t = 1$. Just fixed the typo, thanks

Comment: The claim is false in general. If $T=1$ then $\max(\mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(b_1),\mathbf{1}_{\{-1\}}(b_1))=1> \max(p,1-p)$ unless $p\in \{1,0\}$.